# NAudio waveform plotting in VS 2013

Tags: naudio-framework

I am using VS 2013 and getting an error when trying to deploy an WAV in my code.

The error is in this line:

```
open.Filter= "Wave File (".wav)|".wav;";
```

Comment: Which language are you using ? To me it looks like you messed with the `"` quotes. It should be (wild guess) `"Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I see in your code:

- The string is not properly enclosed.
- You probably want the `*` wildcard character instead of `"` (which solves the first isssue).

So you probably want `open.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav";`.

Comment: thanks a bunch, i actually missed the asterisk character (*).. and I'm using C#.